# How to start Safari on a browser page only when Error 502 stops happening?

Tags: terminal, safari, bash

I've got a situation where if I push an update to an instance on the web, it will take 3-5 minutes to compile, then when that compiling has successfully finished, the instance will shoot **Error 502** for a couple of minutes before it will start running again.

I'm looking for a solution where, the instance (a server URL) will be queried every 5 seconds or so, and when it stops replying **502**, Safari will boot up.

Any idea how I could do that? So far, on the terminal, I can run this:

```
curl -I http://url 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d$' ' -f2
```

and this will output the HTTP Port response or whatever, but I'm not savvy enough to "do that every 5 seconds" or to define a "If (resulting response) is X, keep repeating loop, but If (resulting response) is Y, then launch Safari with an URL".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "quick and dirty" script to accomplish what you are looking to do could be written as:

```
#!/bin/bash

url = "http://url"
code=`curl -I $url 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d$' ' -f2`

while [ "$code" == 502 ]
do
  sleep 5
  echo trying again
  code=`curl -I $url 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d$' ' -f2`
done

open -a Safari $url
```

Basically, what it does is caputure the value that you output in a variable called `code`.  It then evaluates that variable in a While/Do loop every 5 seconds until the value changes.  Once that happens, it exists the loop and launches a Safari instance pointing to the URL.

Comment: Thanks for solving most of the issue - this is good enough to help me in the future. Of course, there's really no way of going "well it loads ok but with previous build for the next 3 minutes, so keep pinging, okay, now it shoots 502, okay, keep pinging.. and now it loads again, so boot up safari with the url". Any ideas on that one @Allan?

Comment: If this is supposed to run continually, you need to run it in the background and disown it.  Execute it by issuing the command:  `script.sh & disown`  (script.sh being the name of the script).  You'll have to modify the loop so it never ends but add a check (if/then) for a code of 200 that will call Safari.  If you only want it to run every 30 mins for example (probably better), add it to `cron` (Linux/BSD/Unix) or `launchd` on the Mac.